# How can I see the asstes copied to the build folder on Xcode 4.3?

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-lion, xcode4.3

I run Xcode 4.3 on a Mac 10.7.4 (Lion).

I have all my resources (images, audio) for my app on a separate folder (something like a DropBox or a sugar Sync folder installed on root) on my system.

I have written a shell script (in run scripts) to copy the resources i need for the app into the bundle when i compile the code.

Is there a way to view the assets (the images and audio) that have been copied in the build folder by my run script? If so, how would i go about doing this?

Comment: Are you asking to know which files in the build folder where copied by your script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select iOS Device as the build target, and build your application. This will generate the product .app file. Expand Products folder from Project Navigator, and right click yourappname.app and select "Show in Finder". Right click the app in your finder and select "Show Package Contents". You will find all your bundled assets there. Please note that you might not be able to open these images.